# node/request keep redirecting to the original URL without return any response

Tags: node.js, redirect, request

I use [request](https://github.com/request/request) to check whether a given URL is broken or not. However, I encountered a strange situation that one given URL keeps redirecting to itself, and the request fails to return any response. But when I open the url with browser, status code 200 is returned.

Anyone knows why request falls into the redirect loop and cannot get the response while the url works find in the browser? How to deal with this problem? Thanks!

```
request({
        uri: 'http://testurl'
        }, function (error, response, body) {
        ......
        }
})
```

The following is the output after setting "request.debug = true"

```
REQUEST { uri: 'http://testurl',
  callback: [Function],
  tunnel: false }
REQUEST make request http://testurl
REQUEST onResponse http://testurl 302 { 'x-cnection': 'close',
  date: 'Wed, 12 Nov 2014 23:59:22 GMT',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  location: 'http://testurl',
  ......,
  'x-powered-by': 'Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1' }
REQUEST redirect http://testurl
REQUEST redirect to http://testurl
REQUEST {}
REQUEST make request http://testurl
REQUEST response end http://testurl 302 { 'x-cnection': 'close',
  date: 'Wed, 12 Nov 2014 23:59:22 GMT',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  location: 'http://testurl',
  ......,
  'x-powered-by': 'Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1' }
REQUEST onResponse http://testurl 302 { 'x-cnection': 'close',
......
```

UPDATE:
 After reading request documentation, I realized it may have something to do with cookies. So I add option **jar: true** to the request, finally it works.

Comment: Thank you for your UPDATE. That solved the issue for me. HUGE help today.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these request options as explained in their documentation:
- followAllRedirects - follow non-GET HTTP 3xx responses as redirects (default: false)
- maxRedirects - the maximum number of redirects to follow (default: 10)

```
request({
    uri: 'http://testurl',
    followAllRedirects: true,
    maxRedirects: 50 // some arbitrary value greater than 10
    }, function (error, response, body) {
    ......
    }
})
```

Is the example a public url? I would like to take a look if this is the case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried this and the url keeps redirecting to itself and eventually exceeds the maxRedirects.